# Linking to an answer in an answer for a dupe

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, duplicate-questions

If a question is a duplicate, it's going to be closed. What should be done with answers to it that just link to another answer by the same person? This seems redundant. I wanna ask you how you behave with this "dupe answer" in such cases, assuming the linked answer is a good one.

- Upvote the answer, because it's a link to a good answer
- Downvote the answer, because it's a duplicate just to earn rep (in your opinion)
- Leave a comment, telling the answerer that you think the answer should be posted as a comment to the duplicating question

Answer (score 5):

Vote to close the question, and leave it at that. You might also want to add a comment, but I wouldn't worry too much about it - if it's genuinely an exact or very close duplicate, I suspect it won't last very long anyway (unless new answers are posted before it's closed which have genuine merit). Move on to another question where your time can be better spent :)

Comment: Yes, just ignore the answers and focus on improving the original.